# Which is the most stable resonating structure of naphthalene and why?

Tags: resonance

I read that the symmetric one is more stable than the other two but I didn't understand why. I am in high school so please keep that in mind

Comment: sorry, but in high school we make 3 different resonating structures and then compare their stability based on factors like charges and all. We get questions like which is more stable R.S. so that's why I required the help of someone who got what was my question. I appreciate your help though

Comment: Try mentioning the word "delocalisation" in class, and see how your teacher reacts. ;-)

Comment: Plus one just because I think too much down votes aren't deserved. It is correct to point out to novices that resonance structure are just descriptors and do not exist. As such, they cannot be called stable or unstable. Tough, one can say a resonance structure has associated  high / low energy.... This is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetric structure is the most stable, as it does not cause a strain of the condensed ring structure because of a longer length of a single bond, which would cause deviation from regular hexagons.

See [Bond Lengths in Naphthalene](http://www.chem.uiuc.edu/organic/Arenes/Chapter%205/sec5-5/5-5.htm). It looks, comparing the measured versus predicted length of the central bond 1+1/3, the symmetric structure is little preferred. It does not tell exactly why, though.

> If we compare the compact pictures of benzene and naphthalene in the orbital representation with the cumbersome resonance representation, we might wonder why the latter picture has survived. The answer is simple: The resonance picture contains a great deal of valuable information which is often obscured in the orbital picture. As an example, suppose we wished to estimate the bond lengths in naphthalene. If we used compact picture, we might guess that they were all the same length. If, however, we chose the resonance picture of and assumed that all three structures made equal contributions to the hybrid we would see that the bond between C-1 and C-2 was double in two of the structures and single in the third. This bond is a 12/3 bond (2/3 double and 1/3 single). By contrast the C-2, C-3 bond is a 11/3 bond (1/3 double and 2/3 single). If we refer to the graph of bond order versus bond length in Fig. 4-3, we observe that a 12/3 bond is predicted to be 1.36 Å long and a 11/3 bond 1.42 Å long. The precise values found for these bonds in naphthalene are 1.364 and 1.404 Å. Although agreement is not perfect, we thus arrive by a simple process at reasonable estimates of bond lengths. Other uses of the resonance picture will become obvious as we proceed, and we shall use both resonance and molecular orbital pictures interchangeably, depending upon which one appears to illustrate a point more clearly.

---

Note that resonating structures are just artefacts of the resonance bond model and do not really exist. following more advanced theory of molecular orbitals, all bonds have character of about 1.5 bond, as $\pi$ electrons are distributed across all the naphthalene structure, not being localized each between just 2 carbon atoms. A question should rather be, if the density of $\pi$ electrons is even, or if some bonds are preferred.